# Como relacionar valor de Json pré-definido com um json de uma chamada AJAX?

Tags: jquery, chartjs, array-push

Faço uma chamada AJAX num endpoint, e isso me retorna um JSON que vou consumir para alimentar um gráfico da lib Chartjs, veja abaixo, o json que é retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com o "name" que refere á criticidade, quero atribuir uma cor específica, como por exemplo para name = Crítica quero definir a cor vermelha... e assim por diante.

- cores pré-difinidas:

```
    var backgroundArrayResult = [];
    var arrayBackgroundColors = {
        'Normal':'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'Baixa':'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        'Acordo':'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'Crítica':'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    }
```

Com o valor de retorno do json armazeno na variável severityData:

```
if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
   $.each(severityData, function (i, itemSeverity) {
      $.each(itemSeverity, function (i, component){
         backgroundArrayResult.push(arrayBackgroundColors[component['name']]);
      });                 
   }); 
}
```

Perceba que já faço um push, já referenciando o valor da variável component(ex.: "Acordo") com o valor da cor pré-definida. Aqui que de fato começa o problema!
Vou dar dois exemplos de como se comporta ao se referenciar com a variável das cores "arrayBackgroundColors" e se eu inserir um valor fixo, por exemplo: "Acordo".

- backgroundArrayResult.push(arrayBackgroundColors[component['name']]);
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- backgroundArrayResult.push(arrayBackgroundColors['Acordo']);
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria isso que eu esperava que trouxesse nesse novo array "backgroundArrayResult"!

Me ajude a identificar o que eu não estou vendo aqui?

Answer (score 0):

Um dos motivos pelo qual os valores do Json esteja "undefined", deve-se ao fato de que se espera um valor de String exatamente ao setado na variável de array "arrayBackgroundColors", como por exemplo: "Acordo". Neste caso deve estar vindo com algum caractere a mais, podendo ser até um espaco ficando assim "Acordo ". Sendo assim, não encontraria este valor dentro do Json de cores e com isso traz undefined. Uma forma de eliminar este possível problema é usando a função do Javascript trim(). Basta apenas inserir no código como o exemplo abaixo:

```
    backgroundArrayResult.push(arrayBackgroundColors[component['name'].trim()]);
```

Com isso deve resolver.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).